# Do some replacement in Haskell List Comprehensions

Tags: string, list, haskell, list-comprehension

My questions is if I put in a string containing such as `Hello, today is a Nice Day!!` How could I get rid of spaces and punctuation and also replacing the uppercase letters with lowercase?

I know how to delete them but not how to replace them.

Also to get rid of the punctuation.

Sorry I don't know how to mess around with strings, only numbers.

```
testList xs = [if x = [,|.|?|!] then " "  | x<-xs]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import Data.Char
```

If you want convert the punctuation to space and the characters from upper case to lower case:

```
testList xs = [if x `elem` ",.?!" then ' ' else toLower x | x<-xs]
```

Example: `testList "TeST,LiST!" == "test list "`

If you want to delete the punctuation and convert the characters from upper case to lower case:

```
testList2 xs = [toLower x | x<-xs, not (x `elem` ",.?!")]
```

Example: `testList2 "Te..S,!t LiS?T" == "test list"`

If you don't want or can not import Data.Char, this is an implementation of toLower:

```
toLower' :: Char -> Char
toLower' char 
    | isNotUppercase = char -- no change required
    | otherwise = toEnum (codeChar + diffLowerUpperChar) -- char lowered
    where
      codeChar = fromEnum char -- each character has a numeric code
      code_A = 65
      code_Z = 90
      code_a = 97
      isNotUppercase = codeChar < code_A || codeChar > code_Z
      diffLowerUpperChar = code_a - code_A
```

Comment: This should have been a comment in my answer. Did you already take a look at it?

Comment: This helps so much. Thank you. The power point that the professor gave us only had examples with numbers but this clears up a lot of my questions for manipulating letters.

Comment: But how would I implement the toLower? It gives me Not in scope and I tried adding the import data.char, but that also gives me an error.     EDIT: I got it to work nvm.

Answer (score 4):

I've been without writing a code in Haskell for a long time, but the following should remove the invalid characters (replace them by a space) and also convert the characters from Uppercase to Lowercase:

```
import Data.Char

replace invalid xs = [if elem x invalid then ' ' else toLower x | x <- xs]
```

Another way of doing the same:

```
repl invalid [] = []
repl invalid (x:xs) | elem x invalid = ' ' : repl invalid xs
                    | otherwise      = toLower x : repl invalid xs
```

You can call the `replace` (or `repl`) function like this:

```
replace ",.?!" "Hello, today is a Nice Day!!"
```

The above code will return:

```
"hello  today is a nice day  "
```

**Edit:** I'm using the `toLower` function from `Data.Char` in Haskell, but if you want to write it by yourself, check here on Stack Overflow. That question has been asked before.

Answer (score 4):

You will find the functions you need in `Data.Char`:

```
import Data.Char

process str = [toLower c | c <- str , isAlpha c]
```

Though personally, I think the function compositional approach is clearer:

```
process = map toLower . filter isAlpha
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem -- OP wants to replace invalid characters by space, not delete them. See @OscarMederos's answer.

Comment: "How could I get rid of spaces and punctuation and also replacing the uppercase letters with lowercase?" That sounds to me like the OP wants to delete spaces.

Comment: Perhaps the OP could edit the question for clarity if he means something else.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the punctuation you can use a filter like this one

```
[x | x<-[1..10], x `mod` 2 == 0]
```

The "if" you are using won't filter. Putting an if in the "map" part of a list comprehension will only seve to choose between two options but you can't filter them out there.

As for converting things to lowercase, its the same trick as you can already pull off in numbers:

```
[x*2 | x <- [1..10]]
```

Comment: So would it be something like [x|x<-xs, x `mod` 2 == 0]?

Comment: @BobBobington No you use `mod x 2` or `x ``mod`` 2` which is easyer to read. It is almost the same like `1 + 2` or `(+) 1 2`

Comment: @BobBobington: You are right. This is what I get for coding too much in Python :P

Comment: @kyticka: In a question you can just use indentation. In a comment you can escape the backticks with a backslash: `\`\\`\`` -> `\``

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version without importing modules, using fromEnum and toEnum to choose which characters to allow:

```
testList xs = 
  filter (\x -> elem (fromEnum x) ([97..122] ++ [32] ++ [48..57])) $ map toLower' xs 
    where toLower' x = if elem (fromEnum x) [65..90] 
                          then toEnum (fromEnum x + 32)::Char 
                          else x

OUTPUT:
*Main> testList "Hello, today is a Nice Day!!"
"hello today is a nice day"
```

For a module-less replace function, something like this might work:

```
myReplace toReplace xs = map myReplace' xs where
  myReplace' x
    | elem (fromEnum x) [65..90] = toEnum (fromEnum x + 32)::Char
    | elem x toReplace           = ' '
    | otherwise                  = x

OUTPUT:
*Main> myReplace "!," "Hello, today is a Nice Day!! 123"
"hello  today is a nice day   123"
```

Comment: Remember that OP wants to replace some characters by a space too.

Answer (score 0):

Using Applicative Style

A textual quote from book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!":

> Using the applicative style on lists is often a good replacement for
> list comprehensions. In the second chapter, we wanted to see all the
> possible products of [2,5,10] and [8,10,11], so we did this:

```
[ x*y | x <- [2,5,10], y <- [8,10,11]]
```

> We're just drawing from two lists and applying a function between
> every combination of elements. This can be done in the applicative
> style as well:

```
(*) <$> [2,5,10] <*> [8,10,11]
```

> This seems clearer to me, because it's easier to see that we're just
> calling * between two non-deterministic computations. If we wanted all
> possible products of those two lists that are more than 50, we'd just
> do:

```
filter (>50) $ (*) <$> [2,5,10] <*> [8,10,11]
-- [55,80,100,110]
```

[Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors)